# How do I append to a list within a dictionary within a list, as identified by another key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with a key for a name and a key for a list of items (amongst other keys). I have a function with parameters of name and item. Dictionaries are checked to see if the name matches, and if the item matches a predetermined set, it becomes MainItem. Otherwise if it matches another predetermined set for misc. items, it gets appended to the "OtherItems" list.

As it stands, my code currently seems to append these misc. items universally as the output of all dictionaries at the end has the same list of OtherItems for all listed dictionaries. Updating MainItem seems to work fine, but I can't get OtherItems to function as intended. Below are a few examples.

```
personList = []
personStats = {"Name": "", "MainItem": "", "OtherItems": []}
```

Modified name-unique copies of personStats gets appended to personList as above for each person and works as intended.

```
def updatePersonItem(name, item):
    itemType = verifyPersonItem(item)
    if itemType == "Main":
        for person in personList:
            if person["Name"] == name:
                person["MainItem"] = name  
    elif itemType == "Misc":
        for person in personList:
            if person["Name"] == name:
                if item not in personStats["OtherItems"]:
                    person["OtherItems"].append(item)
```

verifyPersonItem() compares the item to the 2 different sets, and returns Main or Misc. I have also written other iterations of updatePersonItem() that still end up with the same result.

While it looks good to me, running the above code and printing personList outputs results similar to below.

```
{"Name": "Bob", "MainItem": "Bag", "OtherItems": ['apple', 'banana', 'mandarin', 'orange', 'pear']}
{"Name": "Alice", "MainItem": "Lunchbox", "OtherItems": ['apple', 'banana', 'mandarin', 'orange', 'pear']}
```

However, I am expecting an output such as below, where only the applicable items are appended as intended.

```
{"Name": "Bob", "MainItem": "Bag", "OtherItems": ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']}
{"Name": "Alice", "MainItem": "Lunchbox", "OtherItems": ['apple', 'mandarin']
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I have found a workaround that seems to function as intended. See below.

```
def updatePersonItem(name, item):
    itemType = verifyPersonItem(item)
    for person in personList:
        if person["Name"] == name: 
            if itemType == "Main":
                person["Main"] = item     
            elif itemType == "Misc":
                if item not in person["OtherItems"]:
                    personOtherItemCopy = person["OtherItems"].copy()
                    personOtherItemCopy.append(item)
                    person["Misc"] = personOtherItemCopy
```

Edit2: I have added a minimal reproducible example of my original code to simulate my original scenario as requested. Hopefully this results in a better solution.

```
import re 

personList = []
personStats = {"Name": "", "MainItem": "", "OtherItems": []}

def addPerson(name):
    if not any(d["Name"] == name for d in personList):
        personStatsCopy = personStats.copy()
        personStatsCopy.update({"Name": name})
        personList.append(personStatsCopy)
    else:
        updatePlayerClass(name, item)

def verifyPersonItem(item):
    verifyItemPattern = re.compile(r'(Lunchbox|Bag|Bento|Apple|Orange|Mandarin|Banana|Pear)')
    classMatch = re.search(verifyItemPattern, item)
    boolean = bool(classMatch)
    if boolean == True:
        if item == "Lunchbox" or item == "Bag" or item == "Bento":
            return ("Main")
        else:
            return ("Misc")
    else:
        print("Invalid item.")

def updatePersonItem(name, item):
    itemType = verifyPersonItem(item)
    if itemType == "Main":
        for person in personList:
            if person["Name"] == name:
                person["MainItem"] = item  
    elif itemType == "Misc":
        for person in personList:
            if person["Name"] == name:
                if item not in person["OtherItems"]:
                    person["OtherItems"].append(item)

addPerson("Bob")
addPerson("Alice")
updatePersonItem("Bob", "Bag")
updatePersonItem("Bob", "Apple")
updatePersonItem("Bob", "Orange")
updatePersonItem("Bob", "Mandarin")
updatePersonItem("Alice", "Mandarin")
updatePersonItem("Alice", "Lunchbox")
updatePersonItem("Alice", "Pear")

print(personList)
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see values in variables which you use in function.

Comment: better create minimal working code - with example data - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: I don't undestand why you have different variables `itemType` and `roleType`. And `person` and `player`. maybe you check value for one `person` but you append it to different `player`. OR maybe you assigned the same list to two persons so when you add item in one person then other person also get this item.

Comment: Apologies, the code here is a soft rewrite of the literal code, I had just missed changing those variables into the new ones here. I have found a workaround that seems to work using the .copy() function. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: new code is very different - and this code really shows that without `.copy()` it could make problem.

Comment: Just make a [mre] that contains ALL the code that is needed to replicate the original problem. Just describing what you THINK your code is doing, does nothing but make it harder for us to help solve the issue.

Comment: I have updated the post to include an example as requested. This simulates a much larger log parser and stats aggregator.